# String being truncated even if nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Columns', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Columns
CREATE TABLE #Columns (column_name nvarchar(max))

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(100)
SET @TableName = 'mytable'

INSERT INTO #Columns 
SELECT 'd.' + column_name + ' as ''' +  column_name + '/old'', i.' + column_name + ' as ''' + column_name + '/new'''
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    table_name = @TableName AND
    data_type <> 'text' AND
    data_type <> 'varbinary' AND
    data_type <> 'image'
ORDER BY 
    ordinal_position

DECLARE @string nvarchar(max)

SELECT @string = COALESCE(@string + ', ', '') + column_name
FROM #columns

PRINT len(@string)
PRINT @string
```

I have a table with over 100 columns. The above will truncate my `@string` and its length is about 10500.

Why is the string being truncated even if I use `nvarchar(max)` and what is the correct way to avoid this truncation?

Comment: the string is not being truncated. The studio management only display the first 4000 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does PRINT len(@string) show the correct length? If so the PRINT @string is the problem. The print does only output up to 4000 chars.

Try

```
SELECT @string
```

in order to output the result as a row which is not truncated.

Comment: yeh, it is true. The print statement does emit the full string. You should use the Select statement..